# Leaving a cell blank in Excel until dates are entered

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have to calculate percentage between two dates and the formula I'm using is:

```
=(MIN(TODAY(),F2)-E2+1)/(F2-E2+1)
```

which is giving me the desired result.

However, when I do not enter any dates in `E2` and `F2`, I get a default result of 4272000% in cell `G2`.

I want `G2` to be blank when no information is available in `E2` and `F2`.

Also it should be blank if I enter dates in one of the cells `E2` or `F2` or even post dates.

I would really appreciate if a formula could be devised in coordination with the above percentage formula to achieve the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- Nested IFs:

  ```
  =IF(E2<>"",IF(F2<>"",(MIN(TODAY(),F2)-E2+1)/(F2-E2+1),""),"")
  ```
- IF and AND :

  ```
  =IF((AND(E2<>"",F2<>"")),(MIN(TODAY(),F2)-E2+1)/(F2-E2+1),"")
  ```

Comment: It works perfectly!   Thanks a ton jcbermu, you're a Saviour